# Need Help Opening, Parsing, and Closing a File in Python

Tags: python

I am  Python newbie and I am trying to learn how to parse files but I really don't even know where to begin. I need to basically find a specific code inside the code to confirm the functionality of the run log supplied to me. I just need help in the steps to: Open a file, parse a file, and close a file on Python. If you need anymore info please let me know. I can't supply the code but I can try to give as much info as I can. Thanks!

Comment: Google those individual steps that you broke down in your question.  If you have trouble on a specific step doing a specific thing then post a question on SO if it isn't already asked.

Answer (score 2):

Opening a file:

```
myLog = open("path/to/my/log", 'r')
```

Loop through the lines:

```
for line in myLog:
    if foundMyThing(line):
        print "Found it!"
```

Close it:

```
myLog.close()
```

Read the docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("myfile.myextension",r) as f:
    for line in f:
        <parse each line>
```